# Azure Multi-Site VPN from One Location

Tags: azure, vpn

We have a client who wants to connect their premises to Azure. Their main hindrance at this point is determining the best way to connect to Azure given their current connectivity configuration. They have two redundant ISP connections going to the head office for internet access. They want to be able to configure a VPN connection to Azure that would operate in a similar way i.e. if ISP A went down it would seamlessly use ISP B and vice versa. The normal multi-site VPN configuration does not fit this since there is one local network behind which means the network behind separate VPNs over each ISP would have overlapping IP address ranges which is not supported. Is such a configuration possible? (See diagram below)

Either that or is there a way to abstract the two ISP connections onto one VPN connection to Azure.

They’re currently considering using a Cisco ASA device to help with this. I’m not familiar with the features of this device so I cannot verify if it will solve their issue.  I know there is also a Cisco ASAv appliance in the Azure marketplace don't know if that could also be a part of a possible solution if they went with such a device.

[required vpn configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyKqn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The Site-to-Site VPN capability in Azure does not allow for automatic failover between ISPs.

What you could do are the following
- Have automation task created that would re-create the local network and gateway connection upon failover.  Manual and would take some RTO to get it up and running
- Use the Cisco CSRs to create a DMVPN mesh.  You should be able to achieve the configuration you want using that option.  You would use UDRs in Azure to ensure proper routing

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check this out. I was actually wondering whether they should be using CSRs as opposed to the ASAs. So in your proposed solution they would use a CSR device on-premises and connect via the CSR appliance in Azure?

Comment: Not much of a cisco expert, but I believe the ASAs on prem are fine, and you would run the CSR1000V in Azure.  Then using DMVPN config, you could configure a failover.  My thoughts anyways

Answer (score 0):

I havent done it in Azure, but here is what you do in AWS (And I am sure there would be parallel in Azure)
Configure a "detached VGW" (virtual Private gateway) in aws. Use DMVPN cloud to connect CSRs to multi-site on-prem.

Also, for failover between ISPs you could have a look at DNS load balancing via a parallel to AWS's Route 53 in Azure.

Reference thread :
https://serverfault.com/questions/872700/vpc-transit-difference-between-detached-vgw-and-direct-ipsec-connection-csr100